# AngularJs not linking through

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

I have a list of employees. Now I want to link each record to an employee profile. But no matter what I do, it's not working.

This is my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in homeCtrl.employees" ng-href="#/werknemer/{{employee.EmployeeId}}">
    <td>{{  employee.Role }}</td>
    <td>{{  employee.Company }}</td>
    <td>{{  employee.FirstName }}</td>
    <td>{{  employee.LastName }}</td>
</tr>
```

My page source looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in homeCtrl.employees" ng-href="#/werknemer/1" class="ng-scope" href="#/werknemer/1">
```

Routes file:

```
.when('/werknemer/{id}', {
        templateUrl: '../views/employee.html',
        controller: 'employeeController',
        controllerAs: 'employeeCtrl'
    })
```

I'm using Angular 1.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

`href` attribute will only work on `a`(anchor) tag. Here you are trying it on `tr` which will obviously not gonna work.

You need to do manual redirection by calling event on `ng-click`

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in homeCtrl.employees" ng-click="doRedirect(employee.EmployeeId)">
    <td>{{  employee.Role }}</td>
    <td>{{  employee.Company }}</td>
    <td>{{  employee.FirstName }}</td>
    <td>{{  employee.LastName }}</td>
</tr>
```

Also do change the way you introduce url parameter in route.

**Code**

```
.when('/werknemer/:id', { //changed `/{id}` to `/:id`
    templateUrl: '../views/employee.html',
    controller: 'employeeController',
    controllerAs: 'employeeCtrl'
})
```

**Controller**

```
//ideally this method can be easily moved out to service, will act as a redirection logic
$scope.doRedirect = function(id){
   $location.path('#/werknemer/'+id)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your templateUrl should be

```
templateUrl: '/views/employee.html',
```

angular always look at the project root, therefore you do no need to traverse up one level.

other than that. it is not advised to use href, you should use ng-click to point to some redirect function.

eg.

```
<anyElement ng-click='goTo("#/werknemer/1")'></anyElement>

...

$scope.goTo = function(route){

    //depending on wether the route param contains the leading "#" you might want to use either of the following.

    $window.location.assign(route);

    OR

    $location.path(route);
}
```

Comment: also ,as the other answer as pointed out, your id param in your route has an incorrect syntax to it.